# case-sensitive languages vs insensitive languages?

Tags: c#, vb.net, programming-languages

visual basic.net is case insensitive so it allows the coder to write without caring or remembering the casing of variables. it also relieves from the 'undeclared variable' errors if you use the variable in another case than the one used in declaration. The fact that its line termination is a line feed makes it even more readable unlike C# or c++ that need good care in the casing and contineous war with following up with the **{}**, matching them and figuring out which is for which.

my question is what are the advantages of c# over vb knowing that both get compiled to MSIL so there is almost no performance difference between the two languages?

Comment: C# is less verbose, and I find it much easier to scan C# code because its structural operators (`{` and `}`) are iconographic in nature. I also find the need to escape newlines with `_` to be very annoying. In any event, this is all highly subjective.

Comment: I don't like this stackoverflow rule to close the topic.

Comment: "This language has nicer syntax than that one for this reason and this reason, so what are the advantages of language1 over language2?"  Of course it's subjective/argumentative.  While there are some objective points here, these questions are always closed on SO.  Move along.

Comment: the case sensitivity doesn't matter much, since you know the casing from convention, and additionally you have intellisense fixing it for you. IMO forcing you to follow the convention everywhere leads to better readable code. When I programmed in Delphi(case-insensitive) my casing was quite inconsistent.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: that's a good point. you can vote to reopen the question and answer that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of Visual Basic and C#. There is no real performance difference. But I know a lot of people, and I can conclude that people prefer C# when they learned the language C/C++ first. And people prefer Visual Basic when they learned Pascal First. It's just the syntax.

Comment: On the other hand, I learned VB6 first and used it for years and now prefer C#.

Comment: "prefer Visual Basic when they learned Pascal First" source?

Comment: Well in my case this is wrong; I come from Pascal but do C# coding only, I find VB very hard to read with its verboseness, strange line termination (instead of statement terminations), and last but not least uncomprehensive keywords which don't match the common terminology (for instance for OO stuff).